# how to count heads or tails flipped in a row?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have code already that randomly flips a "coin" 100 times then tells how many times heads was flipped and tails was flipped. Now i'm trying to figure out how to list how many times Heads and/or tails was flipped in a row without the other variation for example: Heads, Heads, Heads. Here is my code:

```js
var NUM_FLIPS = 100;

function start() {
  var flips = flipCoins();
  printArray(flips);
  countHeadsAndTails(flips);
}

function flipCoins() {
  var flips = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++) {
    if (Randomizer.nextBoolean()) {
      flips.push("Heads");
    } else {
      flips.push("Tails");
    }
  }
  return flips;
}

function printArray(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    println(i + ": " + arr[i]);
  }
}

function countHeadsAndTails(flips) {
  var headcount = 0;
  var tailcount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < flips.length; i++) {
    if (flips[i] == "Heads") {
      headcount++;
    } else {
      tailcount++;
    }
  }

  println("Total Heads: " + headcount);
  println("Total Tails: " + tailcount);
}
```

Comment: Just print it in your function where you find the random heads.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this situation is use two new variables: a Boolean variable to detect whether you're counting heads in a row (true) or tails in a row (false) and an unsigned integer to count the number of flips in a row.  You could compare the Boolean that was just flipped in the flipCoins() function with the Boolean that I mentioned earlier in this answer; if they are the same, increment the integer count, and if they are different, reset it to zero.